# Saving a bytearray with php received from Flex Air app

Tags: apache-flex, file, air, arrays, remoteobject

I have an Air application with remote service in codeigniter.
I'm trying to save a bytearray that I received from the Air app 
but when I save the data I get empty files with the correct filename.

So there must be something wrong with my bytearray or the way I save the data.
Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?
I've debugged the Arraycollection I sent and the bytearray is definitely in there.

```
public function uploadImage($image)
{

    foreach($image as $img)
    {

        $file = $img['name'];
        $data = new ByteArray($img['bytes']);

        file_put_contents( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/test/' .$file, $data);

    }

}
```

Comment: I just use the pngencoder from actionscript 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for those who are interested in the solution, aparrently I just had to change this `$data = new ByteArray($img['bytes']);` into this `$data = $img['bytes’]->data;`